# KendoUI Grid with DatePicker column doesnot return correct Data

Tags: datepicker, kendo-grid

I am facing issue with grid inline editing with one of the Date type column. Following are the corresponding code

### cshtml

---

```
id: “ItemId”,
fields: {
ItemId: { editable: false, nullable: true },
Name: { validation: { required: true } },
FromDate: { validation: { required: true }, type: “date”},

columns: [
{ field: “Name”, width: “150px” },
{ field: “FromDate”, title:”Active From”, width: “150px”, format: “{0:dd MMM yyyy}”},
```

All works fine till loading data in to the grid and then when I choose to edit the row FromDate field does have DatePicker. Change the date correct date is displayed and datepicker closed. But then when I try to update this edited data to DB The date available to

```
public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
```

is {01-01-0001 00:00:00} and not the new date I have selected.

Comment: Two more points:
1) This issue is there even when I dont change FromDate. Say If I make changes only to Name column and Update, even then the date passed to FromDate is {01-01-0001 00:00:00}                                       
2)I changed DateTime FromDate { get; set; } to DateTime? FromDate { get; set; }. Then the date passed in any scenario is ‘null’

Comment: I think the issue is in `format: “{0:dd MMM yyyy}”}` try like   this `format: "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"}`